# LocalHost to online via Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I have ready news site on localhost (rails server)
What I should do to put it online (on domain)

I am rookie, so sorry for my bad description.

Comment: This question is too broad and does not belong on SOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to go for hosting service i.e. https://www.heroku.com. They have free plans and easy deploy process. I suppose this would be more than enough for start.

Be aware, if you want to to store user uploaded files, you should connect amazon S3 or something similar to your app.